# passing data to jquery modal aside from adding parameters to url?

Tags: ajax, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

On click of a #dtDelete button I am opening an ajax modal in bootstrap 3.  I am also passing a parameter, selected, along with it and using $_GET on the php page to retrieve it.

As the value of selected may or may not be extremely large I think I should avoid passing the value this way / using $_GET.

How the heck can I pass values other than this method?  Due to the nature of opening the modal (loading it then showing it) I am stuck on any other ways.

```
$('#dtDelete').on('click', function () {
    //open the modal with selected parameter attached
    $('#modal-ajax').load('/modals/m_keystroke_delete.php?selected='+selected);
    $('#modal-ajax').modal('show');                         
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a data object as a second param to [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for it to make a POST request.

```
$('#dtDelete').on('click', function () {

    var data = { 'propertyA': 'extremely large data' };

    //open the modal with selected parameter attached
    $('#modal-ajax').load(
      '/modals/m_keystroke_delete.php?selected=' + selected, // url
      data,                                                  // data
      function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) { } // complete callback
    );

    $('#modal-ajax').modal('show');                         
});
```

You can even pass your "selected" param through the POST request and use `$_POST` or even `$_REQUEST` to retrieve the data. Also notice that the modal now shows once the request has completed.

```
$('#dtDelete').on('click', function () {

    var data = {
      'selected': selected
      'largeData': '...'
    };

    $('#modal-ajax').load(
      '/modals/m_keystroke_delete.php',
      data,
      function() {

        // Invoke the delete-function
        deleteComp();

        // Show the modal
        $(this).modal('show');
      }
    );
});
```

Comment: I had no idea you could do that.  Thank you soo much... you just opened up a lot of possibilities for me.  I'm sure it was obvious, but just beginning with all of this I didn't know. Thanks!

Comment: One more question... in some cases I was doing something like this `$('#modal-ajax').load('/modals/m_keystroke_delete.php?selected='+selected, deleteComp);` where I was calling a function at the end.  Can I do this with your second method as well and if so how?

Comment: The third param is for your callback function. My second example uses an anonymus function. Call your "deleteComp" function within it. Updated my post.